# Trebuchet Projectile Kinetic Energy

Tags: physics, alternative-proof, classical-mechanics

Recently I have been trying to solve a problem relating to trebuchet mechanics for physics, but I am stuck on the mathematics.

The problem goes like this;

For a trebuchet with arm ratio $d_1\over d_2$, sling length $l$, counterweight drop height $h$, projectile mass $m$ counterweight mass $M$ and sling angle to arm $\theta$ ([Trebuchet Variables Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I3um.png)) calculate the final kinetic energy of the projectile (on release) to determine the effect of changing the mass of the projectile each launch.

My solution is as follows (it is shortened):

$E_k={1\over 2} mv^2,$ $K_r={1\over 2} I_t ω^2,$ $E_g=mgh$

$ω=\sqrt{2K_r\over I_t}$

$\therefore v=r\sqrt{2K_r\over I_t}$

$\therefore E_k={1\over 2} mr\sqrt{2K_r\over I_t}^2$

$Assuming$ $100%$ $energy$ $transfer:$

$E_g=K_r$

$I_t=Σmr^2$

$∴I_t=m(d_1+{l\over \sinh⁡(θ)} )^2 +Md_2^2$

$∴E_k={1\over 2} mr \sqrt{2Mgh\over m(d_1+{l\over \sinh⁡(θ)})^2 +Md_2^2}^2$

$Since$ $r=d_1+d_2+{l\over \sinh⁡(θ)}$

$∴E_k={m(d_1+d_2+{l\over \sinh⁡(θ)})^2 Mgh\over (m(d_1+{l\over \sinh⁡(θ)})^2 +Md_2^2}$

This solution assumes a lot, ([In Picture Form for Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QXrY.png)) can anyone present a more accurate solution than mine which still fulfills the initial requirements?

Also, any ideas of how to calculate the efficiency of a system like this? If you have any ideas please contribute :)

Comment: Don't insert a picture "for space". Write out the necessary information.

Comment: The meaning of "$100\%$ efficiency" in the solution is unclear. Even without air resistance or friction it is unreasonable to assume all the potential energy of the system is converted to kinetic energy of the projectile, because at the instant the projectile is release the weight is still moving (or has just hit the ground in an inelastic collision, so there's energy absorbed there).

Comment: The velocity of the projectile is also related to $\dot\theta$ in any remotely realistic trebuchet model, because the whole point of the sling is that the angle $\theta$ changes as the arm rotates. There doesn't seem to be any way to account for this in the given model. Also I see no way to know if you used $\sinh(\theta)$ in the way that was intended, because the intended way to use it is a mystery.